# spring boot Redis configuration - Connection failure occurred. Restarting subscription task after 5000 ms

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, redis, spring-data

I have a following spring boot redis configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConnectionConfiguration {
@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    return redisTemplate;
}

@Bean
RedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = null;
        jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
        jedisConnectionFactory.setHostName(host);
        jedisConnectionFactory.setPort(port);
        jedisConnectionFactory.setTimeout(0);
        jedisConnectionFactory.setPassword(password);
        JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();


        jedisPoolConfig.setMaxTotal(20);
        jedisPoolConfig.setMaxIdle(9000);
        jedisPoolConfig.setMinIdle(16);
        jedisPoolConfig.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        jedisPoolConfig.setTestOnReturn(true);
        jedisPoolConfig.setTestWhileIdle(true);
        jedisPoolConfig.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(60000);
        jedisPoolConfig.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(60000);
        jedisPoolConfig.setNumTestsPerEvictionRun(3);
        jedisPoolConfig.setBlockWhenExhausted(true);
        jedisConnectionFactory.setPoolConfig(jedisPoolConfig);

    return jedisConnectionFactory;
}

@Bean
MessageListenerAdapter messageListener() {
    return new MessageListenerAdapter(eventListenerService);
}

@Bean
ChannelTopic topic() {
    return new ChannelTopic(com.mds.core.common.Constants.REDIS_TOPIC_NAME);
}

@Bean
RedisMessageListenerContainer redisContainer() {
    final RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    container.addMessageListener(messageListener(), receiverTopic());
    container.setTaskExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4));
    return container;
}


@Bean
ChannelTopic receiverTopic() {
    return new ChannelTopic(com.mds.core.common.Constants.REDIS_FRONT_BACK_TOPIC_NAME);
}
```

}

This is redis version and port.

Redis 4.0.6 (00000000/0) 64 bit
Port: 6376

This is spring application.yaml

```
spring:
  profiles: local, default
  mvc:
  view:
    prefix: /
    suffix: .jsp

  redis:
    host: 127.0.0.1
    password: welcome
    port: 6376
```

When I start the spring boot application, it boots fine, but a little later, I start getting the following errors. The following error doesn't stop.

[pool-2-thread-1] ERROR requestId= o.s.d.r.l.RedisMessageListenerContainer 647 - Connection failure occurred. Restarting subscription task after 5000 ms

I am just using the default redis configuration file which comes with the redis zip file. I only changed the password.

But even though I get the error message, the spring web application works fine. The session is created and I have no problem using the web application on local machine.   I even tested it with clustered redis (3 instances) with haproxy(redis port: 6376). Basically, spring web application works fine with the clustered redis.

But I don't think that I can deploy it into the production environment without figuring out the error message.

Does anybody know why I am getting this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have a very similar configuration to you. Application works fine locally. When I deploy it to a test environment it also works but eventually I start seeing that same error in the logs.

Comment: I am sorry that I don't remember exactly what I did, but I vaguely remember that I played around with the values in the redis config.